# JavaScript - POST to URL not sending data

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension, request, fetch

I'm trying to send POST data from a Chrome extension to a website controlled by me. However, when sending the POST data I don't receive any.

I'm sending it using this function:

```js
async function httpPost(url, data) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return response.json();
}
```

It is being called like so:

```php
const post = await httpPost("https://example.com/api", extracted);
```

Where `extracted` contains something similar to `{entries: [], total: 0 }`.

I've tried `console.log` on `httpPost`, `response`, `post` which did not gave anything useful besides that they're working correct.

On the server side, doing a `isset` for `$_POST` does work. The request is sending and is being received. However, doing `file_put_contents('test.txt', print_r($_POST));` leaves the file empty. It is being accessed, just empty.

CORS Headers are set:

```php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

What could this very frustrating issue be?

Desired output: Being able to receive the POST data that I sent with `httpPost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php - if you want to capture the output of `print_r` into a string (so you can write it to a file, for example!) You need to set the `return` parameter, as noted in the documentation. Right now that's probably just printing the post  variables back into the AJAX response, instead of into the file.

E.g. try this:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', print_r($_POST, true));
```

---

**Edit:**

Since you're actually sending JSON in the request, none of the above is particularly applicable anyway.

Similar to the answer in [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

you would read in the JSON data into a string, like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Now, to process this in general, you'd run `json_decode()` on it to turn it into a PHP variable (object, or array depending on the exact content and your preference). But if you simply want to write this data into a file, you might as well just write the raw JSON directly, so you could simply do this:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', $json);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This does indeed work for the printing part - text.txt now contains an empty array: `Array()`. However, it does not contain any post data, that I send using the fetch?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed you're sending JSON from the client. In PHP you need to read incoming JSON differently than you do with regular form data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php for how to do that. (P.S. If all you want to do is write the JSON data direct to the file without processing it, there's probably no point in running json_decode on it, you could just write the raw string direct.)

Comment: Ah. Thanks for pointing that out. Would've never figured it out otherwise. Thanks a ton.